# How to get value of the form field in Symfony 4 when validation fails?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have two dropdowns in my form . Options in second dropdown depend on selected value in the first dropdown. If validation fails I need to get posted value of the first dropdown to set options in the second dropdown. So how to receive posted value in the form type class when validation fails?

Answer (score 1):

```
$form = $this->createForm(MyFormType::class);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    /**
     * Do your stuff when form is valid
     */
} else {
    /**
     * Here you can get the input data even failed with $form->getData()
     */
    dump($form->getData());
}
```

`$form->getData()` gives me the values of input that didn't failed in the else:

```
array:4 [▼
  "first_dropdown" => "hello"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

$advert = new Advert();

```
    $form = $this->createForm(AdvertType::class, $advert, ['method' => 'POST'])
        ->handleRequest($request);

    if (false === $form->isSubmitted()) {
        $form->submit([]);
    }

    if (false === $form->isValid()) {
        return ['form' => $form];
    }

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $this->appendTags($advert);
    $manager->persist($advert);
    $manager->flush();

    return $advert;
```

Comment: This is the Best way

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like below, in my form type class eg. DocType in buildForm() method I did:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals(); 
$myObjectId = $request->request->get('doc')['object']; // selected option of the first dropdown
$object = ($obectId) ? $objectRepository->find($objectId) : null;
```

Then I could use fetched object, to populate second dropdown, using query builder.